# When I click on the library setting "Metadata navigation settings" or "Per-location view settings " got the error: Object reference not set to an

Tags: managed-metadata, filter

I am using sp2010. I have a document library with documents. I have 3 managed metadata columns in this library. When I go to the library settings and click on the option "Metadata navigation settings" or "Per-location view settings" I got an error in the gui.

[image]

When I search in the ULS log I found this error. What is going wrong?

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   
 at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings.ManagedIndexRefFromXmlNode(XmlNode eachManagedIndexNode)    
 at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings.InitializeDataFromXmlString(String newXmlString)    
 at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings.TryCreateFromXml(String propertiesXml)    
 at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings.GetMetadataNavigationSettings(SPList sourceList)    
 at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.Pages.MetaNavSettingsPage.OnLoad(EventArgs args)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I try also this powershell script but give me the same error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb https://portal.myCompany.net/projects/25010095/EXEC/
    $web.Title
    $list = $web.Lists[18]    
    $listNavSettings = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings]::GetMetadataNavigationSettings($list)
```

UPDATE
Also when I go to the site settings (https://portal.boskalis-extra.net/projects/25010095/EXEC/_layouts/settings.aspx) I got the gui message "An unexpected error has occured". this is the ULS error:

```
Timestamp               Process                                     TID     Area                            Category                        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
09/02/2014 18:14:39.38  w3wp.exe (NLBXSP001:0x188C)                 0x1EBC  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:https://portal.myCompany.net:443/projects/25010095/EXEC/_layouts/settings.aspx)   b3eae675-2b6b-4f5d-abc3-14df24f37edd
09/02/2014 18:14:39.40  w3wp.exe (NLBXSP001:0x188C)                 0x1EBC  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Site=/projects/25010095 b3eae675-2b6b-4f5d-abc3-14df24f37edd
09/02/2014 18:14:39.46  w3wp.exe (NLBXSP001:0x188C)                 0x1EBC  Document Management Server      Document Management             ee40    Medium  The following key [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] already found in the collection of type [MetadataNavigationCollection`1].  Ignoring the Add operation. b3eae675-2b6b-4f5d-abc3-14df24f37edd
09/02/2014 18:14:39.46  w3wp.exe (NLBXSP001:0x188C)                 0x1EBC  Document Management Server      Document Management             ee40    Medium  The following key [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] already found in the collection of type [MetadataNavigationCollection`1].  Ignoring the Add operation. b3eae675-2b6b-4f5d-abc3-14df24f37edd
09/02/2014 18:14:39.46  w3wp.exe (NLBXSP001:0x188C)                 0x1EBC  Document Management Server      Document Management             ee40    Medium  The following key [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] already found in the collection of type [MetadataNavigationCollection`1].  Ignoring the Add operation. b3eae675-2b6b-4f5d-abc3-14df24f37edd
09/02/2014 18:14:39.49  w3wp.exe (NLBXSP001:0x188C)                 0x1EBC  Document Management Server      Document Management             ee40    Medium  The following key [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] already found in the collection of type [MetadataNavigationCollection`1].  Ignoring the Add operation. b3eae675-2b6b-4f5d-abc3-14df24f37edd
09/02/2014 18:14:39.49  w3wp.exe (NLBXSP001:0x188C)                 0x1EBC  Document Management Server      Document Management             ee40    Medium  The following key [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] already found in the collection of type [MetadataNavigationCollection`1].  Ignoring the Add operation. b3eae675-2b6b-4f5d-abc3-14df24f37edd
09/02/2014 18:14:39.49  w3wp.exe (NLBXSP001:0x188C)                 0x1EBC  Document Management Server      Document Management             ee40    Medium  The following key [00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] already found in the collection of type [MetadataNavigationCollection`1].  Ignoring the Add operation. b3eae675-2b6b-4f5d-abc3-14df24f37edd
09/02/2014 18:14:39.49  w3wp.exe (NLBXSP001:0x188C)                 0x1EBC  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings.ManagedIndexRefFromXmlNode(XmlNode eachManagedIndexNode)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings.InitializeDataFromXmlString(String newXmlString)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings.TryCreateFromXml(String propertiesXml)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationSettings.GetMetadataNavigationSettings(SPWeb web, Guid sourceListId, Boolean checkWebPropHint)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationContext.GetMetadataNavigationHintsForList(SPWeb w... b3eae675-2b6b-4f5d-abc3-14df24f37edd
09/02/2014 18:14:39.49* w3wp.exe (NLBXSP001:0x188C)                 0x1EBC  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...eb, Guid listGuid)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataHierarchyNodeSiteObject.get_HasChildren()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.DataBindRecursive(TreeNode node, IHierarchicalEnumerable enumerable, Boolean ignorePopulateOnDemand)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.PerformDataBinding()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPTreeView.PerformDataBinding()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.PerformSelect()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPTreeView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.U...  b3eae675-2b6b-4f5d-abc3-14df24f37edd
09/02/2014 18:14:39.49* w3wp.exe (NLBXSP001:0x188C)                 0x1EBC  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...I.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   b3eae675-2b6b-4f5d-abc3-14df24f37edd
09/02/2014 18:14:39.49  w3wp.exe (NLBXSP001:0x188C)                 0x1EBC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:https://portal.myCompany.net:443/projects/25010095/EXEC/_layouts/settings.aspx)). Execution Time=105.015162541608 b3eae675-2b6b-4f5d-abc3-14df24f37edd
```

Comment: have you searched for the correlation id in your uls logs?

Comment: Have you by any chance tested if the same metadata column definition gives the same issues if recreated on another site collection ? may as well be the hidden metatata list getting out of sync.

Comment: Have you deleted any Views or Folders in that Library prior to receiving the error message?  
You can verify by checking in the Site Collection Recycling Bin.

Comment: yes, see my topic. There you see the ULS error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Do you resolve this problem ? I have exactly the same issue but in a Sharepoint 2013 farm :-( Absolutely no idea how to fix it. See you